# inserting to a linked list using helper functions

Tags: c, linked-list, adt

In insert I am attempting to insert a pair, one key and another called value.
I've been trying to get my insert function to work which looks like this
The error I put in keeps being called up saying that a key already exists, which, it doesn't.

```
void insert(Dictionary D, char* key, char* value){
  Node N;
  if(lookup(D,key)!= NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Dictionary Error:  calling insert() on a key that already exists %s\n  ", key);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  }else{
    if(D-> == NULL){//if the list is empty
      N = newNode(key);
      N->next = D->head;
      D->head = N;
      D->tail = N;

      D->head->next = newNode(value);

    }else{
      D->tail->next=newNode(key);
      D->tail= newNode(key);
      D->tail = newNode(value);
      D->tail = newNode(value);   




    }
  }
  D->numItems++;
  D->numItems++;
}
```

My lookup and findKey functions look like so:

```
//lookup()
//returns the value v such that k, v is in D, or returns NULL if no
//value v exists
char* lookup(Dictionary D, char* key){

  if(findKey(D, key)==NULL){
    return NULL;
  }else{
    Node N = findKey(D, key);
    return N;//changed this at lookup, when I write to string make sure that this works
  }
}

//findKey()
//returns a reference to hte node at position of the key in the dictionary
Node findKey(Dictionary D, char* key){
  Node N = NULL;
  N = D->head;
  while(N != NULL){
    if(strcmp(N->item, key)==0){
      N = N->next;
    }
    return N;
  }
  return N;
}
```

Comment: In nthe `insert` function, you don't need to call `lookup` twice. After the first call you *know* it will return `NULL` for the second call as well, making the whole inner `if` statement redundant, and the inner `else` body will never run at all. Also, trying to insert a duplicate key may b an error, but it probably shouldn't be a fatal one causing the whole application to exit.

Comment: And in `lookup` you don't need to call `findKey` twice either. Just call it once in a `return` statement. Actually, why have a `lookup` function at all? Why not call `findKey` directly?

Comment: There's also some mismatch in the declared return type of `lookup` and what you actually return. Does it even build?

Comment: Yes it does build the first one but after that it throws out the error.

Comment: `Dictionary` and `Node` with `*` hidden behind `typedef`s? I've seen this naming convention in another question here on SO. Is this a homework? Did your instructor hand you the declarations, or just names? Can we see the .h file?

Answer (score 1):

In the `findKey` function, you will not loop at all, you will unconditionally return in the very first iteration of the loop.

I think you mean to do e.g.

```
Node findKey(Dictionary D, char* key){
  Node N = NULL;
  N = D->head;
  while(N != NULL){
    if(strcmp(N->item, key)==0){
      return N;
    }
    N = N->next;
  }
  return N;
}
```

Note that I switched place of two lines: The inner `return` statement and the `N = N->next;` statement.

Comment: Maybe instead of `return N` in the `if` block, `break`? Only stylistic difference.

Comment: ok so I made the changes you recommended as well as one other in the inner if loop, which I had a typo in and now I just get a Segmentation fault(core dumped) error

Comment: @JoseLopez To find the cause of that, run your program in a debugger. And it's out of scope for this question, so if you need help with that please post a new question, with a debugger function call stack backtrace included please.